# My ListBox doesn't update when deleting or adding items, despite data binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

All my data bindings work throughout the application. I've tried every mode for the databinding ItemsSource. The List is loaded at the beginning, but doesn't update when I use the context menu I made. I've tested with `WriteLine` to make sure everything else works, and it does.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single" BorderThickness="0" 
    SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Data.SelectedFeedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Data.SelectedFeed, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data.Feeds}" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Title}" 
                    Visibility="Collapsed" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" Padding="1" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="New" Command="{Binding Path=Data.NewFeed}" />
                <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=Data.DeleteFeed}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ListBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=Data.DeleteFeed}" />
        </ListBox.InputBindings>
    </ListBox>
```

**The property**

```
private List<Feed> _Feeds = new List<Feed>();
public List<Feed> Feeds
{
    get
    {
        return _Feeds;
    }
    set
    {
        _Feeds = value;
        onPropertyChanged("Feeds");
    }
}
```

**The command**

```
public ICommand DeleteFeed
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(ExecuteDeleteFeed, CanDeleteFeed);
    }
}

public void ExecuteDeleteFeed(object parameter)
{
    Feeds.RemoveAt(SelectedFeedIndex);
    SelectedFeedIndex = nextIndex;
    onPropertyChanged("Feeds");
}

public bool CanDeleteFeed(object parameter)
{
    return Feeds.Count > 1;
}
```

I recieve the index through binding with the above ListBox:

```
private int _SelectedFeedIndex;
public int SelectedFeedIndex
{
    get
    {
        return _SelectedFeedIndex;
    }
    set
    {
        _SelectedFeedIndex = value;
        onPropertyChanged("SelectedFeedIndex");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried changing to `ObservableCollection`, but I get the following error.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Feeds' property not found on 'object' ''Library' (HashCode=60811181)'. BindingExpression:Path=Data.Feeds; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=34760343); target element is 'ListBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Feeds' property not found on 'object' ''Library' (HashCode=60811181)'. BindingExpression:Path=Data.Feeds; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=34760343); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

The new property

```
ObservableCollection<Feed> Feeds = new ObservableCollection<Feed>();
```

Oh, okay. I made it into a property. It works now. Thanks so much. I thought you only needed ObservableCollection if you didn't use INotifyProperty manually for all the properties. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your List to be an ObservableCollection because the List class does not generate events to notify that its contents have changed. As a result the ListBox will show the initial contents of the List but then never update afterwards. ObservableCollection does generate change events and will do what you need.

Comment: It doesn't work even if you use INotifyProperty for all properties in the class? I'm trying it right now, but I get an error. I'll add it to the post.

Comment: Ah, you need to add INotifyCollectionChanged on the collection class itself so that the ListBox can see when items have been added and removed from the collection. INotifyPropertyChanged would be used on the Feed class to notify a change in property values.